# Изображение, которое является ссылкой - не отображается как изображение html

Tags: html, ссылки

Не могу понять в чем проблема. Отображаются альты, а не картинки[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<html>  
       <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title> Автомобили</title>
       </head>
       <body>
            <H1 align = "center"> Автомобили </H1> 
            <HR>
            <table border="1" align = "center"> 
                <tr>
                    <th> <i>Марка</i></th>
                    <th> <i>Cкорость</i></th>
                    <th> <i>Вес</i></th>
                    <th> <i>Стоимость</i></th>
                    <th> <i>Изображение</i></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> Mercedes ML 350</td>
                    <td> 200 км/ч</td>
                    <td> 2000 кг</td>
                    <td> 30000$ </td>
                    <td> <a href="https://i.infocar.ua/i/2/1343/87079/1920x.jpg"> 
                    <img scr="https://st2.depositphotos.com/1102480/7110/i/950/depositphotos_71103767-stock-photo-mercedes-benz-logo-printed-on.jpg" height= "100" width="100" alt= "мерс"> </a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> Lada Vesta 4</td>
                    <td> 150 км/ч</td>
                    <td> 1600 кг</td>
                    <td> 15000$ </td>
                    <td> <a href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/26/Vladimir_Putin_driving_Lada_Vesta_04.jpg"> 
                    <img scr="http://www.kolesa.ru/uploads/bnnews/2015/04/03/73ec69a3ae4d8ac165d00a5b21a5a7e0.jpg" height= "100" width="100" alt= "лада"> </a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> Mitsubishi Galant 8</td>
                    <td> 180 км/ч</td>
                    <td> 1700 кг</td>
                    <td> 20000$ </td>
                    <td> <a href="https://avtoexperts.ru/wp-content/uploads/SZUt1cDx.jpg"> 
                    <img scr="https://cdn.ddaudio.com.ua/assets/images/alfa-romeo/logo/Mitsubishi_logo_standart.png" height= "100" width="100" alt= "митсубиши"> </a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> Volvo v40</td>
                    <td> 175 км/ч</td>
                    <td> 1580 кг</td>
                    <td> 13000$ </td>
                    <td> <a href="https://www.telegraph.co.uk/cars/images/2016/08/10/2016-Volvo-V40-main_trans_NvBQzQNjv4Bq7e2RPJYDSQSRTYGgROYqbbpjkeyBVM6SW23EFEr_cQ8.jpg?imwidth=450"> 
                    <img scr="https://a.d-cd.net/b5d7378s-960.jpg" height= "100" width="100" alt= "volvo"> </a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> Toyota Camry</td>
                    <td> 220 км/ч</td>
                    <td> 1200 кг</td>
                    <td> 33000$ </td>
                    <td> <a href="https://toyota-ua.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2017/10/Banner_Toyota-Camry_1360x760_1_1.jpg"> 
                    <img scr="https://a.d-cd.net/a3758fu-960.jpg" height= "100" width="100" alt= "тойота"> </a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
       </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Поменяйте `scr` на `src`.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена. Не scr, а src. Прошу прощения за свою невнимательность